# Choose a pdf from sdcard and convert it to byte array in android studio

Tags: android, arrays, pdf, android-intent

I need to choose a pdf from sdcard and convert it to byte array. I don't want to show it . I searched a lot but there was no answer to this question.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == SELECT_MAGAZINE_FILE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        // Let's read picked image data - its URI
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        System.out.println(uri);
        System.out.println(uri.getPath());
        File file = new File(uri.getPath());
            //init array with file length
        byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            fis.read(bytesArray); //read file into bytes[]
            fis.close();

            System.out.println(bytesArray);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

and I got this error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/primary:myfile.pdf: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware for your help.

I changed my code to this and it works. It is better to do it with AsyncTask.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == SELECT_MAGAZINE_FILE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        // Let's read picked image data - its URI
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        File file = new File(uri.getPath());

        try {
            InputStream is = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            byte[] bytesArray = new byte[is.available()];
            is.read(bytesArray);

            //write to sdcard
            /*
            File myPdf=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myPdf.pdf");
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(myPdf.getPath());
            fos.write(bytesArray);
            fos.close();*/

            System.out.println(fileString);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At best, your code will only work if the `Uri` being delivered to `onActivityResult()` happens to have a `file` scheme. Yours does not. It has a `content` scheme. Your code will also fail a lot due to an `OutOfMemoryError`, because your code fails to allocate the `byte[]`. PDF files can be rather large.

So, your first task is to find some other solution instead of reading the entire PDF file into a `byte[]`, as this will be unreliable, and there is nothing that you can do to fix that, other than by not doing it.

Eventually, to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`, use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`.

And, in the long term, you need to move this I/O to a background thread, as right now you will freeze your UI for the time that it takes you to read in the data.

Note that the use of `ContentResolver` for `Uri` values, and the use of threads, is covered in any decent book or course on Android app development.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        Log.d("++++++++++", "++++ data log +++" + imageBitmap);
    }
}
```